# lua_gettop returns 0 but the stack does not behave like it is empty

Tags: c++, lua

When I run the following bit of code:

```
pState = luaL_newstate();
if( !pState )
    return false;

luaL_requiref( pState, "_G", luaopen_base, 1 );
luaL_requiref( pState, "table", luaopen_table, 1 );
luaL_requiref( pState, "string", luaopen_string, 1 );
luaL_requiref( pState, "math", luaopen_math, 1 );
luaL_requiref( pState, "debug", luaopen_debug, 1 );
luaL_requiref( pState, "package", luaopen_package, 1 );
lua_pop( pState, 6 );
// Clear stack 
lua_settop( pState, 0 );

//...

lua_newtable( pState );
lib_indx = lua_gettop( pState );
CLuaManager::PrintStack( pState );
```

The value of `lib_indx` is 0, and my `PrintStack` function (which is the same one presented in the [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html)) shows that the stack is empty. However, if I try to perform any actions that would use the value at the top of the stack, they work as if the table is at the top of the stack. For example, the following code:

```
lua_newtable( pState );
lib_indx = lua_gettop( pState );
lua_setglobal( pState, "TestTable" );
```

Does not result in an error, and the table "TestTable" can be accessed through the script:

```
function dump(o)
   if type(o) == 'table' then
      local s = '{ '
      for k,v in pairs(o) do
         if type(k) ~= 'number' then k = '"'..k..'"' end
         s = s .. '['..k..'] = ' .. dump(v) .. ','
      end
      return s .. '} '
   else
      return tostring(o)
   end
end

print("TestTable:", dump(TestTable))
```

Commenting out the line `lua_setglobal( pState, "TestTable" );` results in an output of `TestTable: nil`, while uncommenting it results in `TestTable: { }`. This shows that the table is being set as the global value `TestTable`. However, `lib_indx` is still zero! So where is Lua finding the table?

Comment: Are you sure that `pState` is a created Lua state object? Can you provide an [mcve] that shows off this behavior? I ask this because 0 is *never* a valid index in the stack; if `luaL_checktype( pState, 0, LUA_TTABLE )` works, it is only by accident.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oops! That's my mistake, you're right that does explain why that works. Interesting that it only works for the `LUA_TTABLE` type. But regardless, my stack does not contain anything despite the docs claiming that `lua_newtable` pushes it onto the stack. And my Lua state object is infact valid, up until now everything has worked as expected. I will change my example to something correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of the behavior. A misplaced `lua_pop` was apparently causing the stack to have a negative size, so the new table was being added to the stack but at an unexpected index.